# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError at comment admin

Tags: mysql, django, unicode, utf-8

I have imported a large set of Arabic Comments from a PHP CMS into this model through SQL query Insert:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(News)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode("%s: %s" % (self.post, self.body[:60]))
```

After insertion, the comments are being shown fine on site but on Django's admin page I get this error:

```
DjangoUnicodeDecodeError at /admin/news/comment/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <Comment: [Bad Unicode data]> (<class 'news.models.Comment'>)
```

Full trackback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/news/comment/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
(u'django.contrib.auth',
 u'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 u'django.contrib.sessions',
 u'django.contrib.sites',
 u'django.contrib.messages',
 u'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 u'django.contrib.admin',
 u'news')
Installed Middleware:
(u'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 91
   ascii
   81 :         {% endif %}


   82 :       {% endblock %}


   83 : 


   84 :       <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post"{% if cl.formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>{% csrf_token %}


   85 :       {% if cl.formset %}


   86 :         <div>{{ cl.formset.management_form }}</div>


   87 :       {% endif %}


   88 : 


   89 :       {% block result_list %}


   90 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}


   91 :            {% result_list cl %} 


   92 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}


   93 :       {% endblock %}


   94 :       {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}


   95 :       </form>


   96 :     </div>


   97 :   </div>


   98 : {% endblock %}


   99 : 

Traceback:
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  139.                 response = response.render()
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  82.         content = template.render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1196.                     _dict = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in result_list
  288.             'results': list(results(cl))}
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in results
  266.             yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in __init__
  258.         super(ResultList, self).__init__(*items)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in items_for_result
  185.             f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py" in lookup_field
  258.                 value = attr()
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __str__
  430.             return force_text(self).encode('utf-8')
File "/home/qliq/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  116.             raise DjangoUnicodeDecodeError(s, *e.args)

Exception Type: DjangoUnicodeDecodeError at /admin/news/comment/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <Comment: [Bad Unicode data]> (<class 'news.models.Comment'>)
```

The database is MySQL 5.5 and all table collations are utf8_unicode_ci.

What is wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post full traceback?

Comment: @PauloBu Full trackback added.

Comment: No one had this problem?

Comment: why not just use return u"%s: %s" % (self.post, self.body[:60]). If the strings you are inserting into the "" are bytestrings, then it would work just fine. If they, in case your database has different encodings for this table, than your database encoding is, then you might need to do encoding changes. Otherwise u"%s: %s" would work just fine.